# Datalife Engine space on URL's

Tags: php, datalife-engine

On DataLife Engine I have a problem in fullstory, the url to all articles of user if using username with space I receive the error, by example: username - **the user** has 3 article, on click to button `<a href="/user/{login}/news">All news</a>`
I receive:
*Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /user/the user/news on this server.*

The url is **site.com/user/the%20user/news** but need to be **site.com/user/the+user/news**

Comment: You are certain changing the encoding of the parameter resolves the issue? I would think spaces in a path would cause issues. The space char would be the same when decoded... If certain use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php instead of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php